# IBM ESSL: DFT - Real to complex & Complex to real - Final array bigger than initial one

Tags: double, fft, complex-numbers, dft

I have a real 2D double precision array. I want to perform a FFT on it, some operations on the result, and an inverse FFT. I am using IBM ESSL library on Blue Gene Q.

The function DRCFT2 is doing the real to complex transform (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFHY8_5.3.0/com.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r3.essl100.doc/am5gr_hsrcft2.htm?lang=en). The function DCRFT2 is doing the complex to real transform (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFHY8_5.3.0/com.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r3.essl100.doc/am5gr_hscrft2.htm?lang=en).

Beginning real array size is (nx,nz). After DRCFT2, the complex array size is (nx/2+1,nz). After DCRFT2, the final real array size is (nx+2,nz).

Beginning and final real arrays have a different size, how can I compare them?

ps: If I put the first real array in a complex one and perform complex to complex DFTs (DCFT2), then the final result and the first one will have the same size and I can compare them. Anyway to do something similar with DRCFT2 and DCRFT2?

Comment: @SleuthEye it looks like you are right. The distinction between the stride and the length of the array was not very clear to me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`DCRFT2` documentation you link to](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFHY8_5.3.0/com.ibm.cluster.essl.v5r3.essl100.doc/am5gr_hscrft2.htm?lang=en):

> **x**
>   is the array `X`, containing `n2` columns of data to be transformed. Due to complex conjugate symmetry, the input consists of only the first `((n1)/2)+1` rows of the array
>   *[...]*
>   **On Return**
>   **y**
>   *[...]*
>   is the array Y, containing `n1` rows and `n2` columns of results of the real discrete Fourier transform of `X`.

Where in you case `n1=nx` and `n2=nz`. In other words, if you put in a complex array of size `(nx/2+1,nz)` as input argument to `DCRFT2` you should get a real array output of size `(nx,nz)`, so you can readily compare your beginning and final real arrays.